# React route component not rendering on the page

Tags: reactjs

I have created a search component, that is supposed to take the user to the page of the pokemon they typed, however, the route is not rendering the component. I am also assigning the value typed in as the param for the url. I am not sure what is going on here, but would really appreciate some help. thank you

```
import React from 'react';
import {HashRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import Search from '../UI/Search'
import './Welcome.css';

let Welcome = (props) => {
    return (
        <Router>
        <div className="welcome-wrapper">
            <h1 className="heading">Welcome to the <b>Pokedex.</b></h1>
            <div>
                <p className="intro">The comprehensive database of Pokemon from the original Blue and Red version.</p>
                <p className="description">Find your favourite and check out their stats</p>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/pokemon/:pokemon" component={Search} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
            
            
        </div>
        </Router>
    );
}

export default Welcome;
```

Search component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './Search.css';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import SearchButton from './SearchButton';
import {colours} from '../../assets/coloursData';


class Search extends Component {
    state = {
        name: "",
        coloursData: [colours],
        imageUrl: "",
        pokemon: "",
        types: [],
        abilities: [],
        stats: {
            hp: "",
            attack: "",
            defense: "",
            specialAttack: "",
            specialDefense: "",
            speed: "",
        },
        display: false,
    }
    
    render() {
        
        const getPokemon = async () => {
            
            try {
            const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${this.state.pokemon}`
            const res = await axios.get(url)
            const name = res.data.name;
            const imageUrl = res.data.sprites.front_default;
            const types = res.data.types.map(type => type.type.name)
            const abilities = res.data.abilities.map(ability => {
                return ability.ability.name.toLowerCase()
                .split('-')
                .map(s => s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1)).join(' ')
            }).join(', ');
            let {hp, attack, defense, specialAttack, specialDefense, speed } = '';
            res.data.stats.map(stat => {
                switch(stat.stat.name) {
                    case 'hp':
                        hp = stat['base_stat']
                        break;
                    case 'attack':
                        attack = stat['base_stat']
                        break;
                    case 'defense':
                        defense = stat['base_stat']
                        break;
                    case 'special-attack':
                        specialAttack = stat['base_stat']
                        break;
                    case 'special-defense':
                        specialDefense = stat['base_stat']
                        break;
                    case 'speed':
                        speed = stat['base_stat']
                        break;
                }
            });
            this.setState({name, imageUrl, types, abilities, hp, attack, defense, specialAttack, specialDefense, speed})
            this.setState({display: true})
            } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
            }
            }
        
        const handleSubmit = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault()
            getPokemon()
        }
        const handleChange = (e) => {
            this.setState({pokemon: e.target.value})
            
        }
        return(
            <Link to={`pokemon/${this.state.pokemon}`}>
            
            <form onSubmit= {handleSubmit}>
                <label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search Pokemon" onChange={handleChange} />
                </label>
                <SearchButton></SearchButton>
            </form>
            
            </Link>
            
            )
    }
        
}
export default Search;
```

Comment: Did you mean to have those methods defined inside the render method of the class component? That aside, what's the URL of your application when you load the application to begin with? That search component won't render at all unless you are exactly on that path with a some path param variable. You might also want to make your path parameter optional eg (path="/pokemon/:pokemon?")

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the Route path was set to a different page. I know I kicking myself.